# assign unique group id to related values between two columns

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, excel

I have a challenging problem.I am developing a web app (.net(C#)) that takes an specific excel file and export an delimited file with specifications explained below.
Here is the excel to be imported:

```
Loan_ID  |Owner_Id | RelPerson_Id | Loan_Class
 ------------------------------------------------
L131231  | 1234    | 5678         | 0
L135148  | 2345    | 6789         | 2
L417128  | 1234    | 5432         | 1
L271237  | 5678    | 1112         | 5
L213781  | 2345    | 1113         | 4
L098932  | 1117    | 6789         | 6
L012213  | 1122    | 3311         | 2
L398721  | 2221    | 1112         | 3
L098766  | 5552    |              | 1
```

Desired output:

```
Cust_ID | Cust_class | Gr_ID    |    Gr.Members                 | Gr_Class
---------------------------------------------------------------------
1234    |   1        |      1   |   (1234,5678,5432,1112,2221)  |   5
2345    |   4        |      2   |   (2345,1117,6789,1113)       |   6
5678    |   5        |      1   |   (1234,5678,5432,1112,2221)  |   5
1117    |   6        |      2   |   (2345,1117,6789,1113)       |   6
1122    |   2        |      3   |   (1122,3311)                 |   2
6789    |   6        |      2   |   (2345,1117,6789,1113)       |   6
5432    |   1        |      1   |   (1234,5678,5432,1112,2221)  |   5
1112    |   5        |      1   |   (1234,5678,5432,1112,2221)  |   5
1113    |   4        |      2   |   (2345,1117,6789,1113)       |   6
3311    |   2        |      3   |   (1122,3311)                 |   2
2221    |   3        |      1   |   (1234,5678,5432,1112,2221)  |   5
5552    |   1        |      4   |   (5552)                      |   4
```

So,i will explain the case in order for you to understand.In the excel file, the first column represents the loan with unique id (no duplicates), the second column represent the Owner of the loan which is an id to identify the customer(Customer_Id).The id of Related person is also a Customer_Id which is the guarantor of the owner in this loan. A customer may have 2 or more loans and can be the guarantor in 2 or more other loans. The guarantor may  be  the guarantor in 2 or three loans but also may be the owner of another loan.So the owner_id and Rel_PersonId may have duplicates and the Rel_PersonId may have blank values . Class column is the rating or classification of the loan Id (Based on days in delay).

From this file i want the above output.
Cust_id is the distinct Customer Id which will be taken from both columns, Owner, and Rel Persons and will be assigned the highest class(Column :Cust_Class) of the loan he is part of(whether owner or guarantor).I already found a solution for the first two columns of the output, i am stuck with grouping.
Grouping logic:Two customers involved in one loan are grouped together, but if any of this customers is involved in another loan(wether like an Owner or a guarantor) with another Cutomer X, and in another with another customer Y both customers will be in a group with the first two, and if customer *x* or *y* are involved in other loans with other customers *z* and *a* those are added to the first group with the others too, and this cycle continues till there are no more customer connected with those that are already in the group.See the desired output for understanding.The group id will be generated automatically and sequentially(1,2,3,4) .The group class will be the class of the customer with the highest Cust_class of the group.
I am using sql server to import the excel.Any idea on how to build a query to gain this output or any other solutions?
Hope you can understand, feel free to ask for any further clarification.
Thank you.

Comment: "*I have a challenging problem.*" - then *what is your try?*

Comment: Another challenging problem is to write SO questions short and simple enough to get people reading and perhaps also answering.