# How to find all connected subgraphs of an undirected graph

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need some help for a problem that i am struggling to solve.

Example table:

```
ID |Identifier1 | Identifier2 
---------------------------------
1  |      a     | c         
2  |      b     | f         
3  |      a     | g         
4  |      c     | h        
5  |      b     | j         
6  |      d     | f         
7  |      e     | k  
8  |      i     |          
9  |      l     | h
```

I want to group identifiers that are related with each other between two columns and assign a unique group id.

Desired Output:

```
Identifier | Gr_ID    |    Gr.Members                 
---------------------------------------------------
a       |      1      |   (a,c,g,h,l)  
b       |      2      |   (b,d,f,j)       
c       |      1      |   (a,c,g,h,l)  
d       |      2      |   (b,d,f,j)       
e       |      3      |   (e,k)                 
f       |      2      |   (b,d,f,j)       
g       |      1      |   (a,c,g,h,l)  
h       |      1      |   (a,c,g,h,l)  
j       |      2      |   (b,d,f,j)       
k       |      3      |   (e,k)                 
l       |      1      |   (a,c,g,h,l)  
i       |      4      |   (i)
```

Note:the column Gr.Members is not necessary, mostly is used for a clearer view.

> So the definition for a group is: A row belongs to a group if it
>   shares at least one identifier with at least one row of this group

But the group id has to be assigned to each identifier(selected by the union of the two columns) not to the row.

Any help on how to build a query to give the desired output?

Thank you.

---

**Update:** Below are some extra sample sets with their expected output.

---

Given table:

```
Identifier1 | Identifier2   
----------------------------
    a       |   f
    a       |   g
    a       |  NULL
    b       |   c
    b       |   a
    b       |   h
    b       |   j
    b       |  NULL
    b       |  NULL
    b       |   g
    c       |   k
    c       |   b
    d       |   l
    d       |   f
    d       |   g
    d       |   m
    d       |   a
    d       |  NULL
    d       |   a
    e       |   c
    e       |   b
    e       |  NULL
```

Expected output: all the records should belong to the same group with group ID = 1.

---

Given Table:

```
Identifier1 | Identifier2
--------------------------
a           |   a
b           |   b
c           |   a
c           |   b
c           |   c
```

Expected output: The records should be in the same group with group ID = 1.

Comment: You want a query as in one query? Because this looks like something that is best done using a `CURSOR` looping over the rows. And does this really have to be done in T-SQL?

Comment: @TT. It is no problem if it can be done with more than one query.Actually this is part of a web app i am developing in .Net(C#). And the table is an excel file.The first idea that came to my mind was to import it in a db and play with queries in order to get the desired output.But i am a junior developer still learning.If you have any better idea, you are welcome

Comment: @TT. Thank you, it was correct apart from the fact that a group_id is assigned also to null values (note that the original table has about 20000 rows) but this is fixable in the select statement.

Comment: Just a quick note, in solving cases like these, having `NULL` in your result is a real bother. Best to replace that with a special value, eg ASCII NUL value.

Comment: Also a question. What's the real-life problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: This is a business case regarding loans and the status of the customers related to this loan.So the identifier 1 and 2 are respectively the owner and the Joint_Holder of the loan.For more information check my detailed question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35013040/assign-unique-group-id-to-related-values-between-two-columns) .Ask me if you need more clarification.

Comment: Is it an absolute necessity to do this in TSQL? Because for some things, TSQL is a drag and won't allow you a solution that performs well...

Comment: @TT. No it isn't necessary.The original table is an excel file and i am developing an web app in .Net(C#) that takes the excel file and exports an csv file with the desired format as i mentioned in the detailed question.I would be happy with any solution that gives me that output.

Comment: @TT. Thank you very much for taking your time to solve this problem, hope it is entertaining for you.
I am in an internship program, and this task is assigned to me.
Even if the last solution gives more accurate results, it also fails in some cases like i described in the second update.

Comment: @TT. This one is a little hard to understand for me.However i need more time to check if the query gives the exact result, but i found a bug that each record that is not paired (ident2 is null or ident1=ident2) is assigned Gr_id =1 .So there are about 9000 records with group Id =1. As i said before this is part of an web app, and i got stuck at this phase .Asked my supervisors for help but they are having trouble too,so i asked here.For this app are required 3 different outputs with 3 different methods of grouping, and if i understand how to do one i will try to do the other two by myself.

Comment: @Stad, I changed the title of the question. I think now it describes the problem better. Please edit it further if you don't agree.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here is a variant that doesn't use cursor, but uses a single recursive query.

Essentially, it treats the data as edges in a graph and traverses recursively all edges of the graph, stopping when the loop is detected. Then it puts all found loops in groups and gives each group a number.

See the detailed explanations of how it works below. I recommend you to run the query CTE-by-CTE and examine each intermediate result to understand what it does.

**Sample 1**

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (ID int, Ident1 char(1), Ident2 char(1));
INSERT INTO @T (ID, Ident1, Ident2) VALUES
(1, 'a', 'a'),
(2, 'b', 'b'),
(3, 'c', 'a'),
(4, 'c', 'b'),
(5, 'c', 'c');
```

**Sample 2**

I added one more row with `z` value to have multiple rows with unpaired values.

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (ID int, Ident1 char(1), Ident2 char(1));
INSERT INTO @T (ID, Ident1, Ident2) VALUES
(1, 'a', 'a'),
(1, 'a', 'c'),
(2, 'b', 'f'),
(3, 'a', 'g'),
(4, 'c', 'h'),
(5, 'b', 'j'),
(6, 'd', 'f'),
(7, 'e', 'k'),
(8, 'i', NULL),
(88, 'z', 'z'),
(9, 'l', 'h');
```

**Sample 3**

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (ID int, Ident1 char(1), Ident2 char(1));
INSERT INTO @T (ID, Ident1, Ident2) VALUES
(1, 'a', 'f'),
(2, 'a', 'g'),
(3, 'a', NULL),
(4, 'b', 'c'),
(5, 'b', 'a'),
(6, 'b', 'h'),
(7, 'b', 'j'),
(8, 'b', NULL),
(9, 'b', NULL),
(10, 'b', 'g'),
(11, 'c', 'k'),
(12, 'c', 'b'),
(13, 'd', 'l'),
(14, 'd', 'f'),
(15, 'd', 'g'),
(16, 'd', 'm'),
(17, 'd', 'a'),
(18, 'd', NULL),
(19, 'd', 'a'),
(20, 'e', 'c'),
(21, 'e', 'b'),
(22, 'e', NULL);
```

**Query**

```
WITH
CTE_Idents
AS
(
    SELECT Ident1 AS Ident
    FROM @T

    UNION

    SELECT Ident2 AS Ident
    FROM @T
)
,CTE_Pairs
AS
(
    SELECT Ident1, Ident2
    FROM @T
    WHERE Ident1 <> Ident2

    UNION

    SELECT Ident2 AS Ident1, Ident1 AS Ident2
    FROM @T
    WHERE Ident1 <> Ident2
)
,CTE_Recursive
AS
(
    SELECT
        CAST(CTE_Idents.Ident AS varchar(8000)) AS AnchorIdent 
        , Ident1
        , Ident2
        , CAST(',' + Ident1 + ',' + Ident2 + ',' AS varchar(8000)) AS IdentPath
        , 1 AS Lvl
    FROM 
        CTE_Pairs
        INNER JOIN CTE_Idents ON CTE_Idents.Ident = CTE_Pairs.Ident1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        CTE_Recursive.AnchorIdent 
        , CTE_Pairs.Ident1
        , CTE_Pairs.Ident2
        , CAST(CTE_Recursive.IdentPath + CTE_Pairs.Ident2 + ',' AS varchar(8000)) AS IdentPath
        , CTE_Recursive.Lvl + 1 AS Lvl
    FROM
        CTE_Pairs
        INNER JOIN CTE_Recursive ON CTE_Recursive.Ident2 = CTE_Pairs.Ident1
    WHERE
        CTE_Recursive.IdentPath NOT LIKE CAST('%,' + CTE_Pairs.Ident2 + ',%' AS varchar(8000))
)
,CTE_RecursionResult
AS
(
    SELECT AnchorIdent, Ident1, Ident2
    FROM CTE_Recursive
)
,CTE_CleanResult
AS
(
    SELECT AnchorIdent, Ident1 AS Ident
    FROM CTE_RecursionResult

    UNION

    SELECT AnchorIdent, Ident2 AS Ident
    FROM CTE_RecursionResult
)
SELECT
    CTE_Idents.Ident
    ,CASE WHEN CA_Data.XML_Value IS NULL 
    THEN CTE_Idents.Ident ELSE CA_Data.XML_Value END AS GroupMembers
    ,DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY 
        CASE WHEN CA_Data.XML_Value IS NULL 
        THEN CTE_Idents.Ident ELSE CA_Data.XML_Value END
    ) AS GroupID
FROM
    CTE_Idents
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT CTE_CleanResult.Ident+','
        FROM CTE_CleanResult
        WHERE CTE_CleanResult.AnchorIdent = CTE_Idents.Ident
        ORDER BY CTE_CleanResult.Ident FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ) AS CA_XML(XML_Value)
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT CA_XML.XML_Value.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
    ) AS CA_Data(XML_Value)
WHERE
    CTE_Idents.Ident IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY Ident;
```

**Result 1**

```
+-------+--------------+---------+
| Ident | GroupMembers | GroupID |
+-------+--------------+---------+
| a     | a,b,c,       |       1 |
| b     | a,b,c,       |       1 |
| c     | a,b,c,       |       1 |
+-------+--------------+---------+
```

**Result 2**

```
+-------+--------------+---------+
| Ident | GroupMembers | GroupID |
+-------+--------------+---------+
| a     | a,c,g,h,l,   |       1 |
| b     | b,d,f,j,     |       2 |
| c     | a,c,g,h,l,   |       1 |
| d     | b,d,f,j,     |       2 |
| e     | e,k,         |       3 |
| f     | b,d,f,j,     |       2 |
| g     | a,c,g,h,l,   |       1 |
| h     | a,c,g,h,l,   |       1 |
| i     | i            |       4 |
| j     | b,d,f,j,     |       2 |
| k     | e,k,         |       3 |
| l     | a,c,g,h,l,   |       1 |
| z     | z            |       5 |
+-------+--------------+---------+
```

**Result 3**

```
+-------+--------------------------+---------+
| Ident |       GroupMembers       | GroupID |
+-------+--------------------------+---------+
| a     | a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,j,k,l,m, |       1 |
| b     | a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,j,k,l,m, |       1 |
| c     | a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,j,k,l,m, |       1 |
| d     | a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,j,k,l,m, |       1 |
| e     | a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,j,k,l,m, |       1 |
| f     | a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,j,k,l,m, |       1 |
| g     | a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,j,k,l,m, |       1 |
| h     | a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,j,k,l,m, |       1 |
| j     | a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,j,k,l,m, |       1 |
| k     | a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,j,k,l,m, |       1 |
| l     | a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,j,k,l,m, |       1 |
| m     | a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,j,k,l,m, |       1 |
+-------+--------------------------+---------+
```

### How it works

I'll use the second set of sample data for this explanation.

**`CTE_Idents`**

`CTE_Idents` gives the list of all Identifiers that appear in both `Ident1` and `Ident2` columns. 
Since they can appear in any order we `UNION` both columns together. `UNION` also removes any duplicates.

```
+-------+
| Ident |
+-------+
| NULL  |
| a     |
| b     |
| c     |
| d     |
| e     |
| f     |
| g     |
| h     |
| i     |
| j     |
| k     |
| l     |
| z     |
+-------+
```

**`CTE_Pairs`**

`CTE_Pairs` gives the list of all edges of the graph in both directions. Again, `UNION` is used to remove any duplicates.

```
+--------+--------+
| Ident1 | Ident2 |
+--------+--------+
| a      | c      |
| a      | g      |
| b      | f      |
| b      | j      |
| c      | a      |
| c      | h      |
| d      | f      |
| e      | k      |
| f      | b      |
| f      | d      |
| g      | a      |
| h      | c      |
| h      | l      |
| j      | b      |
| k      | e      |
| l      | h      |
+--------+--------+
```

**`CTE_Recursive`**

`CTE_Recursive` is the main part of the query that recursively traverses the graph starting from each unique Identifier. 
These starting rows are produced by the first part of `UNION ALL`. 
The second part of `UNION ALL` recursively joins to itself linking `Ident2` to `Ident1`.
Since we pre-made `CTE_Pairs` with all edges written in both directions, we can always link only `Ident2` to `Ident1` and we'll get all paths in the graph.
At the same time the query builds `IdentPath` - a string of comma-delimited Identifiers that have been traversed so far.
It is used in the `WHERE` filter:

```
CTE_Recursive.IdentPath NOT LIKE CAST('%,' + CTE_Pairs.Ident2 + ',%' AS varchar(8000))
```

As soon as we come across the Identifier that had been included in the Path before, the recursion stops as the list of connected nodes is exhausted.
`AnchorIdent` is the starting Identifier for the recursion, it will be used later to group results. 
`Lvl` is not really used, I included it for better understanding of what is going on.

```
+-------------+--------+--------+-------------+-----+
| AnchorIdent | Ident1 | Ident2 |  IdentPath  | Lvl |
+-------------+--------+--------+-------------+-----+
| a           | a      | c      | ,a,c,       |   1 |
| a           | a      | g      | ,a,g,       |   1 |
| b           | b      | f      | ,b,f,       |   1 |
| b           | b      | j      | ,b,j,       |   1 |
| c           | c      | a      | ,c,a,       |   1 |
| c           | c      | h      | ,c,h,       |   1 |
| d           | d      | f      | ,d,f,       |   1 |
| e           | e      | k      | ,e,k,       |   1 |
| f           | f      | b      | ,f,b,       |   1 |
| f           | f      | d      | ,f,d,       |   1 |
| g           | g      | a      | ,g,a,       |   1 |
| h           | h      | c      | ,h,c,       |   1 |
| h           | h      | l      | ,h,l,       |   1 |
| j           | j      | b      | ,j,b,       |   1 |
| k           | k      | e      | ,k,e,       |   1 |
| l           | l      | h      | ,l,h,       |   1 |
| l           | h      | c      | ,l,h,c,     |   2 |
| l           | c      | a      | ,l,h,c,a,   |   3 |
| l           | a      | g      | ,l,h,c,a,g, |   4 |
| j           | b      | f      | ,j,b,f,     |   2 |
| j           | f      | d      | ,j,b,f,d,   |   3 |
| h           | c      | a      | ,h,c,a,     |   2 |
| h           | a      | g      | ,h,c,a,g,   |   3 |
| g           | a      | c      | ,g,a,c,     |   2 |
| g           | c      | h      | ,g,a,c,h,   |   3 |
| g           | h      | l      | ,g,a,c,h,l, |   4 |
| f           | b      | j      | ,f,b,j,     |   2 |
| d           | f      | b      | ,d,f,b,     |   2 |
| d           | b      | j      | ,d,f,b,j,   |   3 |
| c           | h      | l      | ,c,h,l,     |   2 |
| c           | a      | g      | ,c,a,g,     |   2 |
| b           | f      | d      | ,b,f,d,     |   2 |
| a           | c      | h      | ,a,c,h,     |   2 |
| a           | h      | l      | ,a,c,h,l,   |   3 |
+-------------+--------+--------+-------------+-----+
```

**`CTE_CleanResult`**

`CTE_CleanResult` leaves only relevant parts from `CTE_Recursive` and again merges both `Ident1` and `Ident2` using `UNION`.

```
+-------------+-------+
| AnchorIdent | Ident |
+-------------+-------+
| a           | a     |
| a           | c     |
| a           | g     |
| a           | h     |
| a           | l     |
| b           | b     |
| b           | d     |
| b           | f     |
| b           | j     |
| c           | a     |
| c           | c     |
| c           | g     |
| c           | h     |
| c           | l     |
| d           | b     |
| d           | d     |
| d           | f     |
| d           | j     |
| e           | e     |
| e           | k     |
| f           | b     |
| f           | d     |
| f           | f     |
| f           | j     |
| g           | a     |
| g           | c     |
| g           | g     |
| g           | h     |
| g           | l     |
| h           | a     |
| h           | c     |
| h           | g     |
| h           | h     |
| h           | l     |
| j           | b     |
| j           | d     |
| j           | f     |
| j           | j     |
| k           | e     |
| k           | k     |
| l           | a     |
| l           | c     |
| l           | g     |
| l           | h     |
| l           | l     |
+-------------+-------+
```

**Final SELECT**

Now we need to build a string of comma-separated `Ident` values for each `AnchorIdent`. 
`CROSS APPLY` with `FOR XML` does it.
`DENSE_RANK()` calculates the `GroupID` numbers for each `AnchorIdent`.

Comment: This one is a little hard to understand for me.However i need more time to check if the query gives the exact result as is a table with more than 20000 rows, but i found a bug that each record that is not paired (ident2 is null or ident1=ident2) is assigned Gr_id =1 .So there are about 9000 records with group Id =1,instead they should have each an unique Gr_id.

Comment: @Stad, that's why it is important to have sample data with all possible variants of the data. I didn't think about this case originally. I slightly updated the query to take it into account.

Comment: thank you for the explanation,the script seems to give the expected result with a table with 10000 rows and it last about 11 sec.But with a table that have 22000 rows it is still executing after 30 minutes.Is there any way to make it perform faster?

Comment: @Stad, It can be done in linear time, i.e. very fast. Wikipedia has description of the algorithm. The T-SQL method shown above is far from optimal, as you already found out. If you still want to do it in T-SQL you can try the following. Instead of trying to find all groups at the same time, pick a single starting Identifier (add `WHERE Ident='a'` to `CTE_Idents` and `CTE_Pairs`), then delete from the big table all identifiers that were appended to this group. Repeat until the big table is empty. At least you could see the progress. Proper indexes on `Ident` columns would not hurt as well.

Comment: @Stad, one more way to make it work in reasonable time, is to find all Identifiers that are not paired first and remove them from the big table. You said that there are 9000 such rows. That would reduce 22K almost in half.

Answer (score 2):

This script produces the outputs for test sets 1, 2 and 3 as required. Notes on the algorithm as comments in the script.

Be aware:

- This algorithm **destroys** the input set. In the script the input set is `#tree`. So using this script requires inserting the source data into `#tree`
- This algorithm does not work for `NULL` values for nodes. Replace `NULL` values with `CHAR(0)` when inserting into `#tree` using `ISNULL(source_col,CHAR(0))` to circumvent this shortcoming. When selecting from the final result, replace `CHAR(0)` with `NULL` using `NULLIF(node,CHAR(0))`.

Note that the [answer using recursive CTEs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35457468/243373) is more elegant in that it is a single SQL statement, but for large input sets using recursive CTEs may give abysmal execution time (see [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35254260/how-to-find-all-connected-subgraphs-of-an-undirected-graph#comment58664276_35457468) on that answer). The solution as described below, while more convoluted, should run much faster for large input sets.

---

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

CREATE TABLE #tree(node_l CHAR(1),node_r CHAR(1));
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX NIX_tree_node_l ON #tree(node_l)INCLUDE(node_r); -- covering indices to speed up lookup
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX NIX_tree_node_r ON #tree(node_r)INCLUDE(node_l);
INSERT INTO #tree(node_l,node_r) VALUES
    ('a','c'),('b','f'),('a','g'),('c','h'),('b','j'),('d','f'),('e','k'),('i','i'),('l','h'); -- test set 1
    --('a','f'),('a','g'),(CHAR(0),'a'),('b','c'),('b','a'),('b','h'),('b','j'),('b',CHAR(0)),('b',CHAR(0)),('b','g'),('c','k'),('c','b'),('d','l'),('d','f'),('d','g'),('d','m'),('d','a'),('d',CHAR(0)),('d','a'),('e','c'),('e','b'),('e',CHAR(0)); -- test set 2
    --('a','a'),('b','b'),('c','a'),('c','b'),('c','c'); -- test set 3 

CREATE TABLE #sets(node CHAR(1) PRIMARY KEY,group_id INT); -- nodes with group id assigned
CREATE TABLE #visitor_queue(node CHAR(1)); -- contains nodes to visit
CREATE TABLE #visited_nodes(node CHAR(1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED WITH(IGNORE_DUP_KEY=ON)); -- nodes visited for nodes on the queue; ignore duplicate nodes when inserted
CREATE TABLE #visitor_ctx(node_l CHAR(1),node_r CHAR(1)); -- context table, contains deleted nodes as they are visited from #tree

DECLARE @last_created_group_id INT=0;

-- Notes:
-- 1. This algorithm is destructive in its input set, ie #tree will be empty at the end of this procedure
-- 2. This algorithm does not accept NULL values. Populate #tree with CHAR(0) for NULL values (using ISNULL(source_col,CHAR(0)), or COALESCE(source_col,CHAR(0)))
-- 3. When selecting from #sets, to regain the original NULL values use NULLIF(node,CHAR(0))
WHILE EXISTS(SELECT*FROM #tree)
BEGIN
    TRUNCATE TABLE #visited_nodes;
    TRUNCATE TABLE #visitor_ctx;

    -- push first nodes onto the queue (via #visitor_ctx -> #visitor_queue)
    DELETE TOP (1) t
    OUTPUT deleted.node_l,deleted.node_r INTO #visitor_ctx(node_l,node_r)
    FROM #tree AS t;

    INSERT INTO #visitor_queue(node) SELECT node_l FROM #visitor_ctx UNION SELECT node_r FROM #visitor_ctx; -- UNION to filter when node_l equals node_r
    INSERT INTO #visited_nodes(node) SELECT node FROM #visitor_queue; -- keep track of nodes visited

    -- work down the queue by visiting linked nodes in #tree; nodes are deleted as they are visited
    WHILE EXISTS(SELECT*FROM #visitor_queue)
    BEGIN
        TRUNCATE TABLE #visitor_ctx;

        -- pop_front for node on the stack (via #visitor_ctx -> @node)
        DELETE TOP (1) s
        OUTPUT deleted.node INTO #visitor_ctx(node_l)
        FROM #visitor_queue AS s;

        DECLARE @node CHAR(1)=(SELECT node_l FROM #visitor_ctx); 
        TRUNCATE TABLE #visitor_ctx;

        -- visit nodes in #tree where node_l or node_r equal target @node; 
        -- delete visited nodes from #tree, output to #visitor_ctx
        DELETE t
        OUTPUT deleted.node_l,deleted.node_r INTO #visitor_ctx(node_l,node_r)
        FROM #tree AS t
        WHERE t.node_l=@node OR t.node_r=@node;

        -- insert visited nodes in the queue that haven't been visited before
        INSERT INTO #visitor_queue(node) 
        (SELECT node_l FROM #visitor_ctx UNION SELECT node_r FROM #visitor_ctx) EXCEPT (SELECT node FROM #visited_nodes);

        -- keep track of visited nodes (duplicates are ignored by the IGNORE_DUP_KEY option for the PK)
        INSERT INTO #visited_nodes(node)
        SELECT node_l FROM #visitor_ctx UNION SELECT node_r FROM #visitor_ctx;
    END

    SET @last_created_group_id+=1; -- create new group id

    -- insert group into #sets
    INSERT INTO #sets(group_id,node)
    SELECT group_id=@last_created_group_id,node 
    FROM #visited_nodes;
END

SELECT node=NULLIF(node,CHAR(0)),group_id FROM #sets ORDER BY node; -- nodes with their assigned group id

SELECT g.group_id,m.members  -- groups with their members
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT group_id FROM #sets) AS g
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT members=STUFF((
                SELECT ','+ISNULL(CAST(NULLIF(si.node,CHAR(0)) AS VARCHAR(4)),'NULL')
                FROM #sets AS si 
                WHERE si.group_id=g.group_id
                FOR XML PATH('')
            ),1,1,'')
     ) AS m
ORDER BY g.group_id;

DROP TABLE #visitor_queue;
DROP TABLE #visited_nodes;
DROP TABLE #visitor_ctx;
DROP TABLE #sets;
DROP TABLE #tree;
```

---

Output for set 1:

```
+------+----------+
| node | group_id |
+------+----------+
| a    |        1 |
| b    |        2 |
| c    |        1 |
| d    |        2 |
| e    |        4 |
| f    |        2 |
| g    |        1 |
| h    |        1 |
| i    |        3 |
| j    |        2 |
| k    |        4 |
| l    |        1 |
+------+----------+
```

---

Output for set 2:

```
+------+----------+
| node | group_id |
+------+----------+
| NULL |        1 |
| a    |        1 |
| b    |        1 |
| c    |        1 |
| d    |        1 |
| e    |        1 |
| f    |        1 |
| g    |        1 |
| h    |        1 |
| j    |        1 |
| k    |        1 |
| l    |        1 |
| m    |        1 |
+------+----------+
```

---

Output for set 3:

```
+------+----------+
| node | group_id |
+------+----------+
| a    |        1 |
| b    |        1 |
| c    |        1 |
+------+----------+
```

Comment: after several testing with different tables with thousand rows  the query is not correct as it does not meet the definition of a group that i specified above.The grouping changes every time the sorting(order by) changes for tables with thousand of records.I will edit the question to explain the case when the error happens, i don't know if this is a right thing to do because i am a new member here.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to use stored procedure with cursor.
It is easy to implement and relatively fast.
Only two steps:

- First, create sp_GetIdentByGroup
- Second, INSERT related identifiers in a temporary table #PairIds and call sp [dbo].[sp_GetIdentByGroup] and you will get Identifiers with the same GroupID as related items.

Query:

```
CREATE TABLE #PairIds
(
    Ident1 VARCHAR(10),
    Ident2 VARCHAR(10)
)

INSERT INTO #PairIds
VALUES ('a', 'c'),
('b', 'f'),
('a', 'g'),
('c', 'h'),
('b', 'j'),
('d', 'f'),
('e', 'k'),
('l', 'h')


exec [dbo].[sp_GetIdentByGroup]
```

Result:

`Ident  | GroupID                
---------------------------------------------------
a       |      1      |   
b       |      2      |        
c       |      1      | 
d       |      2      |      
e       |      3      |                
f       |      2      |       
g       |      1      |  
h       |      1      |  
j       |      2      |         
k       |      3      |                 
l       |      1      |`

Code for creating stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_GetIdentByGroup]
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @message VARCHAR(70);
    DECLARE @IdentInput1 varchar(20)
    DECLARE @IdentInput2 varchar(20)
    DECLARE @Counter INT
    DECLARE @Group1 INT
    DECLARE @Group2 INT
    DECLARE @Ident varchar(20)
    DECLARE @IdentCheck1 varchar(20)
    DECLARE @IdentCheck2 varchar(20)

    SET @Counter = 1

    DECLARE @IdentByGroupCursor TABLE (
    Ident varchar(20) UNIQUE CLUSTERED,
    GroupID INT  
    );


    -- Use a cursor to select your data, which enables SQL Server to extract
    -- the data from your local table to the variables.
    declare ins_cursor cursor for
    select  Ident1, Ident2 from #PairIds



    open ins_cursor
    fetch next from ins_cursor into @IdentInput1, @IdentInput2 -- At this point, the data from the first row
     -- is in your local variables.

    -- Move through the table with the @@FETCH_STATUS=0
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
    BEGIN

        SET @Group1 = null
        SET @Group2 = null

        SELECT TOP 1  @Group1 = GroupID,  @IdentCheck1 = Ident
        FROM @IdentByGroupCursor
        WHERE Ident in (@IdentInput1)

        SELECT TOP 1  @Group2 = GroupID,  @IdentCheck2 = Ident
        FROM @IdentByGroupCursor
        WHERE Ident in (@IdentInput2)

        IF (@Group1 IS NOT NULL AND @Group2 IS NOT NULL)
        BEGIN
            IF @Group1 > @Group2
            BEGIN
                UPDATE @IdentByGroupCursor
                SET GroupID = @Group2
                WHERE
                GroupID = @Group1
            END

            IF @Group2 > @Group1
            BEGIN
                UPDATE @IdentByGroupCursor
                SET GroupID = @Group1
                WHERE
                GroupID = @Group2
            END
        END
        ELSE IF @Group1 IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN
            UPDATE @IdentByGroupCursor
            SET GroupID = @Group1
            WHERE
            Ident IN (@IdentInput1)
        END
        ELSE IF @Group2 IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN
            UPDATE @IdentByGroupCursor
            SET GroupID = @Group2
            WHERE
            Ident IN (@IdentInput2)
        END

        IF (@Group1 IS NOT NULL AND @Group2 IS NOT NULL)
        BEGIN
            IF @Group1 > @Group2
            BEGIN
                UPDATE @IdentByGroupCursor
                SET GroupID = @Group2
                WHERE
                GroupID = @Group1
            END

            IF @Group2 > @Group1
            BEGIN
                UPDATE @IdentByGroupCursor
                SET GroupID = @Group1
                WHERE
                GroupID = @Group2
            END

        END

            IF @Group1 IS NULL
            BEGIN

                INSERT INTO @IdentByGroupCursor (Ident, GroupID)
                VALUES (@IdentInput1, ISNULL(@Group2, @Counter))

            END

            IF @Group2 IS NULL
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO @IdentByGroupCursor (Ident, GroupID)
                VALUES (@IdentInput2, ISNULL(@Group1, @COunter))
            END

            IF (@Group1 IS NULL OR @Group2 IS NULL)
            BEGIN

            SET @COunter =  @COunter  +1

        END

        -- Once the execution has taken place, you fetch the next row of data from your local table.
        fetch next from ins_cursor into @IdentInput1, @IdentInput2

    End


    -- When all the rows have inserted you must close and deallocate the cursor.
    -- Failure to do this will not let you re-use the cursor.    
    close ins_cursor
    deallocate ins_cursor


    SELECT Ident ,DENSE_RANK() OVER( ORDER BY GroupID ASC) AS GroupID
    FROM @IdentByGroupCursor
    ORDER BY Ident

END
GO
```

Sp_GetIdentByGroup has an index for speed and with the use of a cursor, it prepares desired result set. The stored procedure expects #PairIds table to exist.

More information on [SQL How to group identifiers that are related with each other in specific groups](http://interestingwebs.blogspot.com/2021/02/sql-how-to-group-identifiers-that-are.html).