# Select all values from a table plus a column returning 1/0 whether a record exists in other table

Tags: mysql, sql

I need some help with a MySQL query which is bringing me a headache.

Basically I have two tables which are related. The first table is called 'books' and it contains the basic information about a book. Then I have an other table called 'user_books' which is related to the previous table and other table (which is irrelevant in the question). This is how the books table looks like:

```
| b_id       |    b_name     |   b_description    |
---------------------------------------------------
| 1          |    Book1      |   Description1     |
| 2          |    Book2      |   Description2     |
```

The 'user_books' table has this content:

```
| ub_userid  | ub_bookid  | ub_rating  | ub_default  |
------------------------------------------------------
| 10         | 1          | 5          | 1           |
```

The user_books table has two primary keys: ub_userid and ub_bookid.

Now I need to make a query which returns all books of the books table and for each book the rating of a given user and a column that in case that there is a record for the book in the user_books table return 1 but if there isn't any book with that bookid return 0.

My desired output given the user 10 would be this:

```
| b_id  | b_name | b_description  | ub_default  | active |
----------------------------------------------------------
| 1     | Book1  | Description1   | 1           |  1     |
| 2     | Book2  | Description2   | 0           |  0     |
----------------------------------------------------------
```

I'm using MySQL 5.7

Thanks so much in advance for any kind of help.

Comment: You described your task, however, you failed to ask any question and you did not provide any reasonable attempt to solve your own question.

Comment: I gave the desired output and I think my question is really clear. I've been many hours trying to solve this question and I won't put every code that I tried...

Comment: If questions are formatted in a specific way, and provide all of the minimum required information, they are much more helpful both to people who are looking to provide answers and for others who might be searching for answers in the future.  Established users are asked to help evaluate newly posted questions and help increase the overall quality of questions.  If you don't ask a specific question, we can't be sure we're giving you the information you need. That being said, there is this post:  https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/

Comment: Again, there is no question in your post, only a task description. Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select 
  b.b_id, 
  b.b_name, 
  b.b_description, 
  coalesce(ub.ub_default, 0) as ub_default,
  case 
    when ub.ub_userid is null then 0 
    else 1 
  end as active  
from books b left outer join 
     user_books ub 
     on ub.ub_bookid = b.b_id
where
     ub.ub_userid = 10;
```

This doesn't do any aggregation, so if you have multiple `user_books` records for one `books` record, then the `books` record will be duplicated.  But, it shows how to join against a missing row (outer join) and test for whether that outer join row is present or missing.

Here's a SQL Fiddle for MySQL 5.6  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b70ff8/4/0

Comment: Thanks for the help. As you said I'm getting duplicated records because in user_books the same book appears for each user. How could I just select the records for a given userid?

Comment: I've added a Where clause, Yogesh is tweaking the code as we speak.

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error in the case

Comment: case was missing 'when'

Comment: Yes, I noticed, however the query is returning only one record instead of two. I don't know why

Comment: The 'where' clause is making it so that only rows that have a user are returned; if you remove the where clause, both records show.  This goes back to having more detailed sample data and desired outcomes; for an example of a question that has lots of sample data with different possible outcomes being tested, see here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42119006/finding-each-customer-groups-most-recent-account/50938197#50938197

Comment: @Osakr the solutions in the duplicate topic will actually overcome this issue with Jeff's code. That's why I linked the duplicate: your question has already been asked and answered.

Comment: I finally got it! Reading that post helped me but that wasn't all ^^ my query is little different because in that post he desires to return only the columns with a given string. I needed to return all columns and add if they exist or not in the other table which has some differences. However the logic was more or less the same, using a LEFT JOIN and two IFs I managed to get what I wanted. Thanks for the help