# SQL Find all transitive matches throughout two columns of matching products

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of product numbers, where the product on the left is an equivalent for the product on the right. Assuming something similar to the transitive property, if product A is a match for B, and B is a match for C, then A is also a match for C. This extends out as far as possible, where if C is also a match for D, then B and A are also matches for D.

I'm trying to find a way that I can snake through both lists and, using a flag, indicate which products group together.

I've tried a few combinations of self-joins and cross-joins but there are too many matches in each group (potentially hundreds) across too many rows of products (about 50,000). I think a recursive CTE may be a solution, but I'm still a bit fuzzy on how they work exactly.

Basically, my data looks like this:

```
Product1 | Product2
  123    |   124
  124    |   126
  125    |   123
  126    |   125
  127    |   129
  128    |   127
  129    |   130
  130    |   128
```

In this case,

```
123 = 124 = 125 = 126
```

and

```
127 = 128 = 129 = 130
```

Therefore, the final output should look like:

```
Product | Group
  123   |   1
  124   |   1
  125   |   1
  126   |   1
  127   |   2
  128   |   2
  129   |   2
  130   |   2
```

I realize that SQL may not be the best application to solve this problem, but this is part of an overall business process that all runs in SQL, so I don't have the option to use Python or something that is more flexible and suited for this kind of task. Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this question is very similar to the one asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35254260/243373). There are two answers to this question: one with recursive CTEs and one a bit more convoluted. They both give the correct output, just note that for very large input sets the convoluted answer (mine ;)) will perform better.

Comment: That's amazing! The output is exactly what I'm looking for based on the post. I'll need some time to go through it and understand how it's working but it's such a relief to know a solution exists.

Comment: Good to hear that.

Answer (score 0):

You'd better construct a undirected graph and DFS it, finding all cycle, each cycle is a group, results are these groups.