# Postgres GROUP BY an array column

Tags: postgresql, group-by, array-agg

I have a list of students and parents and would like to group them into families using the student id's. Parents who share common student id's can be considered to be a family while also students who share common parent id's can be considered to be a family. This is a sample table:

```
 p_id | parent_name | s_id | student_name |
------------------------------------------|
 1    | John Doe    | 100 |  Mike Doe     |
 3    | Jane Doe    | 100 |  Mike Doe     |
 3    | Jane Doe    | 105 |  Lisa Doe     |
 5    | Will Willy  | 108 |  William Son  |
```

I'd like to end up with something like:

```
     parents       |       students         |
-------------------|------------------------|
John Doe, Jane Doe |  Mike Doe, Lisa Doe    |
Will Willy         |  William Son           |
```

To achieve this I'm currently using:

```
SELECT array_agg(parents) AS parents FROM (
    SELECT array_agg(p_id) AS par_ids, array_agg(parent_name) AS parents, student_name, s_id 
    FROM (
        /* sub query */
    )b
    GROUP BY s_id, student_name
    ORDER BY parents ASC
)c
GROUP BY unnest(par_ids)
ORDER BY parents ASC
```

But I get an error: `ERROR:  cannot accumulate arrays of different dimensionality`. `SQL state: 2202E`

How can I attain the desired results?
The inner query from the above statement returns:

```
| par_ids |       parents       |  student_name   | s_id |
--------------------------------|------------------------|
| {1,3}   | {John Doe, Jane Doe}|  Mike Doe       | 100  |
| {3}     | {Jane Doe}          |  Lisa Doe       | 105  |
| {5}     | {Will Willy}        |  William Son    | 108  |
```

Grouping these students now to the parents is where I'm stuck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did something similar (but a bit more complex) already here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53129510/3984221

---

[step-by-step demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=f6081e8fa6c23a7b799c595a0a3b5eea)

```
SELECT
    array_agg(parent_name) as parents,                -- 4
    array_agg(student_name) as students
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (t.s_id)                       -- 3
        *
    FROM (
        SELECT
            s_id,
            array_agg(p_id) as parents                -- 1
        FROM mytable
        GROUP BY s_id
    ) s JOIN mytable t ON t.p_id = ANY(s.parents)     -- 2
    ORDER BY t.s_id, CARDINALITY(parents) DESC        -- 3
) s
GROUP BY parents
```

1. Aggregate the `p_id` values into an array:

   | s_id | parents |
   | --- | --- |
   | 108 | {5} |
   | 105 | {3} |
   | 100 | {1,3} |
2. Self-join the original table on this array:

   | s_id | parents | p_id | parent_name | s_id | student_name |
   | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
   | 100 | {1,3} | 1 | John Doe | 100 | Mike Doe |
   | 105 | {3} | 3 | Jane Doe | 100 | Mike Doe |
   | 100 | {1,3} | 3 | Jane Doe | 100 | Mike Doe |
   | 105 | {3} | 3 | Jane Doe | 105 | Lisa Doe |
   | 100 | {1,3} | 3 | Jane Doe | 105 | Lisa Doe |
   | 108 | {5} | 5 | Will Willy | 108 | William Son |
3. Remove all duplicate student records. The remaining ones should be the records with the most complete `p_id` array. This can be done using `DISTINCT ON(s_id)` on a descending order by the array length:

   | s_id | parents | p_id | parent_name | s_id | student_name |
   | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
   | 100 | {1,3} | 1 | John Doe | 100 | Mike Doe |
   | 100 | {1,3} | 3 | Jane Doe | 105 | Lisa Doe |
   | 108 | {5} | 5 | Will Willy | 108 | William Son |
4. Finally you can group by the `p_id` array and aggregate the two `name` columns:

   | parents | students |
   | --- | --- |
   | {"John Doe","Jane Doe"} | {"Mike Doe","Lisa Doe"} |
   | {"Will Willy"} | {"William Son"} |

If you don't want to get an array, but a string list, you can use `string_agg(name_colum, ',')` instead of `array_agg(name_column)`

Comment: Thanks. This really helped me out. Couldn't figure a way around it.