# MSSQL Grouping by Nested Values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to group by a series of nested relationships.  Use the following example.  Assuming each persons name is unique to the database.

```
Person | Sibling 1 | Sibling 2
-------+-----------+-----------
Jason  | Brad      | Sheri
Brad   | Sheri     | Jason
Sheri  | Brad      | Tina
Tina   | Sheri     | Sam
Sam    | Kara      | Tina
Kara   | Sam       | Tina
James  | Kelly     | NULL
Kelly  | James     | NULL
Fred   | NULL      | NULL
```

How would I write the query to get this result?

```
Person | Family
-------+--------
Jason  | 1
Brad   | 1
Sheri  | 1
Tina   | 1
Sam    | 1
Kara   | 1
James  | 2
Kelly  | 2
Fred   | 3
```

Ideally with out the use of external code such as CLR or CTEs.

**EDIT:**  The following output is also acceptable.

```
Family | Siblings
-------+-------------------------------------
1      | Jason, Brad, Sheri, Tina, Sam, Kara
2      | James, Kelly
3      | Fred
```

Comment: You would help us (and yourself) a great deal if you explain the logic behing column `Family`. E.g. why does Fred get `Family`=`3`, even though he occurs just once in the Person table?

Comment: Because Fred does not have any siblings therefor he must be an only child of his own family.  I need to build this family group by evaluating all the member of the family and then grouping them all together

Comment: I still don't understand, please try to explain it better. What does what you just said have to do with the value **`3`** ?

Comment: This is more complex than it seems and it's a problem of graphs. Please have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35254260/how-to-find-all-connected-subgraphs-of-an-undirected-graph

Comment: I was hoping to do this with out any cursors or CTE's.  Do you think its possible?

Comment: The family values are auto numbers by the group/partition.  The actual values are irrelevant as long as they are unique per "family".

Comment: @BKSwindell I don't think it's possible to solve with a simple query, unless you use graph functionalities available on SQL Server 2017 (which requires specific table and data types).

Comment: We are working with SQL 2008 so that is not possible.  Ok i will need to figure out how we would do it with the CTE.  We are working with a dataset of 500k rows and need to make sure it operates very quickly.  My experense with CTEs and Cursors are that they are very slow.

Comment: is `Tina` sibling for `Jason` ? Let us know this login of your desire output.

Comment: Yes Tina is related to Jason because she is related to Sheri who is related to Jason.

Comment: Essentially we need to build a list of all siblings that are related as @EzLo suggesst in his link.  If i could build 3 CSV strings of "Jason, Brad, Sheri, Tina, Sam, Kara" and then "James, Kelly", and finally "Fred" that would be the first step.  The rest would be easy.

Comment: Is there a known and guaranteed upper limit on family members?

Comment: Im not sure yet as i have not been able to evaluate the data to that level.  But I'm assuming there are not more then 10 or so.

Comment: I have added the alternate output to the question.

Comment: @BKSwindell this is a graph problem. If, and only if there are no cycles, you could treat it as a hierarchy, and add a `hiearchyid` to represent families and relations. CTEs aren't slow - they are nothing more than subqueries that can also be used recursively. They are slow if the query is slow, if there are missing indexes etc. `hierarchyid` removes the need for recursion if you can model your relations as a DAG

Comment: @BKSwindell you can use CTEs to generate the hierarchyid values needed to improve performance in this table. Once the migration is finished, you can update the `hierarchyid` column each time you modify a row

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach to your question (using CTE):

```
declare @tb table (Person varchar(10), Sibling1 varchar(10), Sibling2 varchar(10))
insert into @tb values
('Jason','Brad', 'Sheri'), ('Brad', 'Sheri','Jason'), ('Sheri','Brad', 'Tina'),
('Tina', 'Sheri','Sam'),   ('Sam',  'Kara', 'Tina'),  ('Kara', 'Sam',  'Tina'),
('James','Kelly',NULL),    ('Kelly','James',NULL),    ('Fred', NULL,   NULL)

with b
as (select
     Person
    ,Related = (select COUNT(*) from @tb where a.Person in (Sibling1, Sibling2))
    from @tb a
    )
select c.Person, Family = 
    case (select SUM(b.Related) from b where b.Person in (c.Person, c.Sibling1, c.Sibling2))
        when 0 then 3
        when 2 then 2
        else 1
    end
from @tb c
```