# How to assign connected subgraph ID to each node in an undirected graph in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, graph, oracle11g

How to partition a set of links in a link_tbl defined by the `from_node` and `to_node`. There are 10M nodes and 25M links (no more than 20 links per node).

For example
[image]

The graph consists of three disjoint subgraphs.

```
  create table link_tbl as (
  select 'AY' as linkid, 'A' as from_node, 'Y' as to_node from dual union all
  select 'AB', 'A', 'B' from dual union all
  select 'CA', 'C', 'A' from dual union all      
  select 'GE', 'G', 'E' from dual union all
  select 'CB', 'C', 'B' from dual union all
  select 'EF', 'E', 'F' from dual union all
  select 'NM', 'N', 'M' from dual
  );
  --compute subnetid
  select * from link_tbl order by subnetid;
```

To get a result set with `subnetid` values?

[image]

I can use a variant of flood fill in Java to assign subgraph id to each node of a graph. But can this be done in SQL?

Pseudocode:
 - Rank nodes with consecutive integers. 
 - Represent links as `(node1*100M + node2) as number(19,0)`
 - Union links node1,node2 with node2, node1 and sort
 - Get first node as an anchor `node` and add to `subgraph_nodes' 
 - Iterate over link table
 -`add node2`to subgraph_nodes if node1 is in (subgraph_nodes) AND node2 not in subgraph_nodes`

This should add all connected nodes  to `subgraph_nodes`

This will be sufficient because now I can add subgraph_id' to node table and select all nodes without `subgraph id` and repeat subgraph analysis.

There are 10M nodes represented as consecutive integers and 25M links (no more than 20 links per node), represented as `(from_node*100M + to_node) as ID, from_node, to_node`.

Comment: What do you mean by partition here? what's a `link_tbl`, what's a node? It is not always obvious to the reader what you have in your mind just by looking at your query. You should make some effort in explaining what you want. Also, adding sample data as image, instead of plain text is not considered a good question. Provide clear and sufficient details for us to help you answer your question.

Answer (score 5):

A while ago I wrote an answer to the question [How to find all connected subgraphs of an undirected graph](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35254260/4116017). It was written for SQL Server, but Oracle supports standard recursive queries, so it was easy to convert it to Oracle. It may be written more efficiently using constructs specific to Oracle.

**Sample data**

```
create table link_tbl as (
  select 'AY' as linkid, 'A' as from_node, 'Y' as to_node from dual union all
  select 'AB', 'A', 'B' from dual union all
  select 'CA', 'C', 'A' from dual union all      
  select 'GE', 'G', 'E' from dual union all
  select 'CB', 'C', 'B' from dual union all
  select 'EF', 'E', 'F' from dual union all
  select 'NM', 'N', 'M' from dual
);
```

**Query**

```
WITH
CTE_Nodes
AS
(
    SELECT from_node AS Node
    FROM link_tbl

    UNION

    SELECT to_node AS Node
    FROM link_tbl
)
,CTE_Pairs
AS
(
    SELECT from_node AS Node1, to_node AS Node2
    FROM link_tbl
    WHERE from_node <> to_node

    UNION

    SELECT to_node AS Node1, from_node AS Node2
    FROM link_tbl
    WHERE from_node <> to_node
)
,CTE_Recursive (AnchorNode, Node1, Node2, NodePath, Lvl)
AS
(
    SELECT
        CAST(CTE_Nodes.Node AS varchar(2000)) AS AnchorNode
        , Node1
        , Node2
        , CAST(',' || Node1 || ',' || Node2 || ',' AS varchar(2000)) AS NodePath
        , 1 AS Lvl
    FROM 
        CTE_Pairs
        INNER JOIN CTE_Nodes ON CTE_Nodes.Node = CTE_Pairs.Node1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        CTE_Recursive.AnchorNode
        , CTE_Pairs.Node1
        , CTE_Pairs.Node2
        , CAST(CTE_Recursive.NodePath || CTE_Pairs.Node2 || ',' AS varchar(2000)) AS NodePath
        , CTE_Recursive.Lvl + 1 AS Lvl
    FROM
        CTE_Pairs
        INNER JOIN CTE_Recursive ON CTE_Recursive.Node2 = CTE_Pairs.Node1
    WHERE
        CTE_Recursive.NodePath NOT LIKE CAST('%,' || CTE_Pairs.Node2 || ',%' AS varchar(2000))
)
,CTE_RecursionResult
AS
(
    SELECT AnchorNode, Node1, Node2
    FROM CTE_Recursive
)
,CTE_CleanResult
AS
(
    SELECT AnchorNode, Node1 AS Node
    FROM CTE_RecursionResult

    UNION

    SELECT AnchorNode, Node2 AS Node
    FROM CTE_RecursionResult
)
SELECT
    CTE_Nodes.Node
    ,LISTAGG(CTE_CleanResult.Node, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CTE_CleanResult.Node) AS GroupMembers
    ,DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY LISTAGG(CTE_CleanResult.Node, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CTE_CleanResult.Node)) AS GroupID
FROM
    CTE_Nodes
    INNER JOIN CTE_CleanResult ON CTE_CleanResult.AnchorNode = CTE_Nodes.Node
GROUP BY
    CTE_Nodes.Node
ORDER BY
    GroupID
    ,CTE_Nodes.Node
;
```

**Result**

```
+------+--------------+---------+
| NODE | GROUPMEMBERS | GROUPID |
+------+--------------+---------+
| A    | A,B,C,Y      |       1 |
| B    | A,B,C,Y      |       1 |
| C    | A,B,C,Y      |       1 |
| Y    | A,B,C,Y      |       1 |
| E    | E,F,G        |       2 |
| F    | E,F,G        |       2 |
| G    | E,F,G        |       2 |
| M    | M,N          |       3 |
| N    | M,N          |       3 |
+------+--------------+---------+
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e61cf73824e7718a4686430ccd7398e7

### How it works

**`CTE_Nodes`**

`CTE_Nodes` gives the list of all Nodes that appear in both `from_node` and `to_node` columns. 
Since they can appear in any order we `UNION` both columns together. `UNION` also removes any duplicates.

```
+------+
| NODE |
+------+
| A    |
| B    |
| C    |
| E    |
| F    |
| G    |
| M    |
| N    |
| Y    |
+------+
```

**`CTE_Pairs`**

`CTE_Pairs` gives the list of all edges of the graph in both directions. Again, `UNION` is used to remove any duplicates.

```
+-------+-------+
| NODE1 | NODE2 |
+-------+-------+
| A     | B     |
| A     | C     |
| A     | Y     |
| B     | A     |
| B     | C     |
| C     | A     |
| C     | B     |
| E     | F     |
| E     | G     |
| F     | E     |
| G     | E     |
| M     | N     |
| N     | M     |
| Y     | A     |
+-------+-------+
```

**`CTE_Recursive`**

`CTE_Recursive` is the main part of the query that recursively traverses the graph starting from each unique Node. 
These starting rows are produced by the first part of `UNION ALL`. 
The second part of `UNION ALL` recursively joins to itself linking `Node2` to `Node1`.
Since we pre-made `CTE_Pairs` with all edges written in both directions, we can always link only `Node2` to `Node1` and we'll get all paths in the graph.
At the same time the query builds `NodePath` - a string of comma-delimited Nodes that have been traversed so far.
It is used in the `WHERE` filter:

```
CTE_Recursive.NodePath NOT LIKE CAST('%,' || CTE_Pairs.Node2 || ',%' AS varchar(2000))
```

As soon as we come across the Node that had been included in the Path before, the recursion stops as the list of connected nodes is exhausted.
`AnchorNode` is the starting Node for the recursion, it will be used later to group results. 
`Lvl` is not really used, I included it for better understanding of what is going on.

```
+------------+-------+-------+-----------+-----+
| ANCHORNODE | NODE1 | NODE2 | NODEPATH  | LVL |
+------------+-------+-------+-----------+-----+
| A          | A     | Y     | ,A,Y,     |   1 |
| A          | A     | C     | ,A,C,     |   1 |
| A          | A     | B     | ,A,B,     |   1 |
| B          | B     | C     | ,B,C,     |   1 |
| B          | B     | A     | ,B,A,     |   1 |
| C          | C     | B     | ,C,B,     |   1 |
| C          | C     | A     | ,C,A,     |   1 |
| E          | E     | G     | ,E,G,     |   1 |
| E          | E     | F     | ,E,F,     |   1 |
| F          | F     | E     | ,F,E,     |   1 |
| G          | G     | E     | ,G,E,     |   1 |
| M          | M     | N     | ,M,N,     |   1 |
| N          | N     | M     | ,N,M,     |   1 |
| Y          | Y     | A     | ,Y,A,     |   1 |
| Y          | A     | B     | ,Y,A,B,   |   2 |
| C          | A     | B     | ,C,A,B,   |   2 |
| Y          | A     | C     | ,Y,A,C,   |   2 |
| B          | A     | C     | ,B,A,C,   |   2 |
| C          | A     | Y     | ,C,A,Y,   |   2 |
| B          | A     | Y     | ,B,A,Y,   |   2 |
| C          | B     | A     | ,C,B,A,   |   2 |
| A          | B     | C     | ,A,B,C,   |   2 |
| B          | C     | A     | ,B,C,A,   |   2 |
| A          | C     | B     | ,A,C,B,   |   2 |
| G          | E     | F     | ,G,E,F,   |   2 |
| F          | E     | G     | ,F,E,G,   |   2 |
| B          | A     | Y     | ,B,C,A,Y, |   3 |
| C          | A     | Y     | ,C,B,A,Y, |   3 |
| Y          | B     | C     | ,Y,A,B,C, |   3 |
| Y          | C     | B     | ,Y,A,C,B, |   3 |
+------------+-------+-------+-----------+-----+
```

**`CTE_CleanResult`**

`CTE_CleanResult` leaves only relevant parts from `CTE_Recursive` and again merges both `Node1` and `Node2` using `UNION`.

```
+------------+------+
| ANCHORNODE | NODE |
+------------+------+
| A          | A    |
| A          | B    |
| A          | C    |
| A          | Y    |
| B          | A    |
| B          | B    |
| B          | C    |
| B          | Y    |
| C          | A    |
| C          | B    |
| C          | C    |
| C          | Y    |
| E          | E    |
| E          | F    |
| E          | G    |
| F          | E    |
| F          | F    |
| F          | G    |
| G          | E    |
| G          | F    |
| G          | G    |
| M          | M    |
| M          | N    |
| N          | M    |
| N          | N    |
| Y          | A    |
| Y          | B    |
| Y          | C    |
| Y          | Y    |
+------------+------+
```

**Final SELECT**

Now we need to build a string of comma-separated `Node` values for each `AnchorNode`. 
`LISTAGG` does it.
`DENSE_RANK()` calculates the `GroupID` numbers for each `AnchorNode`.

---

### Efficiency

You have rather large tables, so trying to find all groups at once in a single query above may be quite inefficient.

One way to make it more efficient is not to use a single query for the whole dataset. Don't try to find all subnets/groups at the same time. Limit the starting point to one node. Add `WHERE CTE_Nodes.Node = 'some node'` to the first part of `CTE_Recursive`. The query will find all nodes of one subnet. Delete these found nodes from the big table, pick another starting node, repeat in a loop until the big table is empty. If you materialise `CTE_Nodes` and `CTE_Pairs` as temp tables with indexes, it may help as well.

I have never worked with Oracle and don't know its syntax for procedural code, so I'll write in a pseudocode below.

**Prepare temp tables**

```
CREATE TABLE Nodes AS
(
    SELECT from_node AS Node
    FROM link_tbl

    UNION

    SELECT to_node AS Node
    FROM link_tbl
);
CREATE INDEX IX_Node ON Nodes (Node);

CREATE TABLE Pairs AS
(
    SELECT from_node AS Node1, to_node AS Node2
    FROM link_tbl
    WHERE from_node <> to_node

    UNION

    SELECT to_node AS Node1, from_node AS Node2
    FROM link_tbl
    WHERE from_node <> to_node
);
CREATE INDEX IX_Node1 ON Pairs (Node1);
CREATE INDEX IX_Node2 ON Pairs (Node2);

CREATE TABLE Subgraph AS
(
    SELECT Node FROM Nodes WHERE 1=0
);

CREATE TABLE Result
(
    GroupID int NOT NULL,
    Node varchar(10) NOT NULL
);
```

```
SET :GroupID = 0;
```

**The main loop starts**

Pick one `Node` from `Nodes`. Any row will do. Save the `Node` into variable. Again, I don't know proper Oracle syntax for it.

```
SELECT :N = Node FROM Nodes WHERE rownum=1;
```

If `Nodes` is empty, stop the loop.

```
SET :GroupID = :GroupID + 1;
```

Run the recursive query starting the recursion from one specific `Node` chosen above.

```
INSERT INTO Subgraph (Node)
WITH
CTE_Recursive (AnchorNode, Node1, Node2, NodePath, Lvl)
AS
(
    SELECT
        CAST(Nodes.Node AS varchar(2000)) AS AnchorNode
        , Node1
        , Node2
        , CAST(',' || Node1 || ',' || Node2 || ',' AS varchar(2000)) AS NodePath
        , 1 AS Lvl
    FROM 
        Pairs
        INNER JOIN Nodes ON Nodes.Node = Pairs.Node1
    WHERE
        Nodes.Node = :N  -- 'A'
        -- use variable here, don't know what the syntax is

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        CTE_Recursive.AnchorNode
        , Pairs.Node1
        , Pairs.Node2
        , CAST(CTE_Recursive.NodePath || Pairs.Node2 || ',' AS varchar(2000)) AS NodePath
        , CTE_Recursive.Lvl + 1 AS Lvl
    FROM
        Pairs
        INNER JOIN CTE_Recursive ON CTE_Recursive.Node2 = Pairs.Node1
    WHERE
        CTE_Recursive.NodePath NOT LIKE CAST('%,' || Pairs.Node2 || ',%' AS varchar(2000))
)
,CTE_Result
AS
(
    SELECT Node1 AS Node
    FROM CTE_Recursive

    UNION

    SELECT Node2 AS Node
    FROM CTE_Recursive
)
SELECT Node FROM CTE_Result
;
```

This query will return all nodes that are connected to the given starting node, i.e. those that form a subgraph.
Save its result set into a `Subgraph` temp table.

Append result into the final `Result` table and allocate an ID to the found subgraph.

```
INSERT INTO Result (GroupID, Node)
SELECT :GroupID, Node
FROM Subgraph;
```

Delete processed nodes from `Nodes` and `Pairs`.

```
DELETE FROM Nodes
WHERE Node IN (SELECT Node FROM Subgraph)
;

DELETE FROM Pairs
WHERE 
    Node1 IN (SELECT Node FROM Subgraph)
    OR
    Node2 IN (SELECT Node FROM Subgraph)
;
```

Clean the `Subgraph` table

```
DELETE FROM Subgraph;
```

Return to the start of the loop.

In the end `Result` table will have all nodes with the corresponding ID of the subgraph.

---

Actually, you can simplify it further. You don't need the `Nodes` table, `Pairs` is enough.

Comment: I have updated the question. Your query works on small sets, but fails on 10M Nodes. Can you rewrite it a bit, so that it manages 10M entries? In particular, the `NODEPATH`   is very memory consuming. The `CAST(...AS varchar(2000))` is slow and can be replaced with `cast(min(node1,node2)*100M + max(node1,node2) as NUMBER(19,0)`. С наградой сочтемся. Спасибо.

Comment: @Stepan, it can be done in linear time https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_(graph_theory), but SQL is not the best language for such task.

Comment: @Stepan, One way to make it more efficient is not to use a single query for the whole dataset. Don't try to find all subnets/groups at the same time. Limit the starting point to one node. Add `WHERE CTE_Nodes.Node = 'some node'` to the first part of `CTE_Recursive`. The query will find all nodes of one subnet. Delete these found nodes from the big table, pick another starting node, repeat in a loop until the big table is empty. If you materialise `CTE_Nodes` and `CTE_Pairs` as temp tables with indexes, it may help as well.

Comment: Can you post an example with a `where node='A'` clause as a separate answer? I can import all links to Java and do the depth first search, but would like to learn see how to do it in SQL.